# Why are corpses blinded with a cloth?

Tags: black-butler

In the Manga, in [The Ship Voyage arc](http://kuroshitsuji.wikia.com/wiki/Ship_Voyage_Arc), the corpses on Campania are blinded by a cloth. Ciel speculates that they can't hear or see. But if the cloth is removed, will they be able to see? Or is it just for show? To depict that the corpses can't see? Any particular reason? Or the Mangaka just wanted to design the characters that way?